# HTML BEM naming convention

Tags: html, css, bem

I am learning HTML BEM (CSS) architecture and quite not really understanding even after watching a few youtube videos. Can anyone of you review my piece of code to see if my class naming is correct?

```html
<div class="chat-offer">

  <div class="img chat-offer__img">
    <picture class="chat-box-b default-box-b">
      <img src="${properties.chatMobileImageBoxA}" alt="${properties.chatBackgroundImageAltText}"              class="offers-img-responsive">
    </picture>
    <picture class="chat-logout default-logout">
      <source media="(min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px)"               srcset="${properties.chatMobileImageBoxA}">
      <source media="(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px)" srcset="${properties.chatMobileImageBoxA}">
      <img src="${properties.chatDesktopImageBoxA}" alt="${properties.chatBackgroundImageAltText}" class="offers-img-responsive">
    </picture>
  </div>

  <div class="chat-offer__txt">
    <h1 class="chat-offer__txt--heading">${properties.offerTitle}</h1>
    <p class="chat-offer__txt--subheading">${properties.offerSubTitle}</p>
    <div class="chat-offer__btn">
      <a href="${chatOfferModel.loginCTALink}" target="${chatOfferModel.loginNewWindow}" class="chat-offer--cta">${properties.loginCTAText}</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The naming looks mostly right. I'd make the following suggestions:

1. I'd change `chat-offer__txt` to `chat-offer__txt-wrapper`. The element you're attaching it to doesn't really have anything in common with the two elements (h1 and p) which you're adding the modified versions of that rule to.
2. Personally, whenever I see a modifier class on an element I would also expect to see the unmodified (element or block) class on the same element. The unmodified class sets up the defaults which the modifier overrides. So `h1.chat-offer__txt.chat-offer__txt--heading` for example.
3. You've got quite a few unrelated "generic" classes mixed in with your BEM, `img`, `chat-box-b`, `default-box-b` for example, which makes it more difficult to reason about the styling and how all these rules will interact. If you're using SASS, it might be worth setting up mixins to include styling which is reusable across multiple components, which will keep your BEM simpler and easier to reason about.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few suggestions based on your implementation:

1. Take a look at the following setup

```
<div class="chat-offer">
  <div class="img chat-offer__img">
    [..]
  </div>
</div>
```

The second div is the `img` element of the `chat-offer` block, but it is not an image. It is better to rename this to `chat-offer__image-container` because that is what is does.. It's the container of the image. That way you can use `chat-offer__image` instead of `offers-img-responsive`. So the new implementation would be:

```
<div class="chat-offer">
  <div class="chat-offer__image-container">
    [..]
    <img class="chat-offer__image />
  </div>
</div>
```

---

2. The same goes for this block:

```
<div class="chat-offer__txt">
  <h1 class="chat-offer__txt--heading">${properties.offerTitle}</h1>
  <p class="chat-offer__txt--subheading">${properties.offerSubTitle}</p>
  [..]
</div>
```

`chat-offer__txt` implies that it's the txt element of the `chat-offer` block, but it is not. It is the text wrapper, so change it to `chat-offer__text-wrapper` with a `chat-offer__title` and `chat-offer__subtitle` (or heading and subheading), making it like this:

```
<div class="chat-offer__text-wrapper">
  <h1 class="chat-offer__title">${properties.offerTitle}</h1>
  <p class="chat-offer__subtitle">${properties.offerSubTitle}</p>
  [..]
</div>
```

---

3. This part can also be improved a bit:

```
<div class="chat-offer__btn">
  <a href="${chatOfferModel.loginCTALink}" 
    target="${chatOfferModel.loginNewWindow}" 
    class="chat-offer--cta">
    ${properties.loginCTAText}
  </a>
</div>
```

The button is the `<a>[..]</a>` part, so name it like that: `chat-offer__button`, currently it is a `--cta` modifier on the `chat-offer` block, so you're basically saying: This is a chat-offer block, but it is the CTA version of it, but it the CTA version of the button within the chat-offer block, making it `chat-offer__button chat-offer__button--cta`. It is important to never use a modifier on it's own, because your css will look a bit like this:

```
.chat-offer__button {
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

.chat-offer__button--cta {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

If you only use the modifier class, it will not use the width and height of the button.

You are getting in the right direction, asking questions is an important part in this, so keep on going!